# JavaScript Library Design

Tags: javascript

I have a general question about the design of JavaScript Libraries.

I am trying to consolidate common methods into one js file so they can be reused by different scripts.

I have taken a look at how the JSON library is structured and believe it was a good approach.
[JSON for Javascript](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

So they start off creating an instance of the class:

```
if (!this.JSON) {
    this.JSON = {};
}
```

Then they do this:

```
(function () {
    if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function') {
        JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {
```

This is works perfect if you just want to do JSON.[function_name], but what if I want to have a more structured library such that I want: JSON.[subgroup].[function].  How would I structure my JS library in such a way?

Any links to resources are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would recommend you to follow the Module Pattern in JavaScript instead of following JSON's pattern strictly. Your subgroup is actually referring to sub-modules. Take a look at the following excellent article:

[Ben Cherry's JavaScript Module Pattern In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)

Other resources you should probably go through:

- [John Resig's Learning Advanced JavaScript](https://johnresig.com/apps/learn/)
- [Seven JavaScript Things I Wish I Knew Much Earlier In My Career](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/20/seven-javascript-things-i-wish-i-knew-much-earlier-in-my-career/)
- [The Seven Deadly Sins Of JavaScript Implementation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/22/the-seven-deadly-sins-of-javascript-implementation/)

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with the module pattern. See http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/no-love-for-module-pattern. I used to use it before but stopped. Now I just tend to keep it simple. If you really want sub-namespacing you can make a simple namespace function for the job.

See
http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2008/05/javascript-namespace-function.html

Comment: I never thought I'd disagree with Jonathon Snook but [his blog post](https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/no-love-for-module-pattern) is saying we should throw out having private variables because then you'd have to use breakpoints. Instead he wants global access to be able to mutate objects at run time. Sounds like he wants to throw out the good parts and keep the bad ones