# Best practice to create Custom UI framework in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks

I want to create a custom UI framework in JavaScript for web applications (like Google Docs ui) (do not confuse with web application that deploy using languages like PHP, Python, etc.). However, after reading several books about web development, I understand that the best website is layered as follows:

1. Structure in HTML
2. Presentation in CSS
3. Behaviour in JavaScript

So there are several approaches to creating my own HTML document and control it in JavaScript. However in this approach HTML and CSS will be mixed, like in case of extJS UI. I am confused now, and I need some answers from experienced developers on how to write this kind of framework.

- If HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is mixed.

  - What was advantages?
  - What was disadvantages?
- Is there are other methods?
- What was the usual type of creating UI frameworks?

Comment: can you state why do u want to create this framework?I mean how is the framework is going to help you do you want to reducing code?usability?functionality?cross browser issue?expose APIs?

Comment: It should good functionality, reducing code generation from users side and support cross browser issue. Also it should consider browsers internal memory consumption with minimal processing time to render ui functionality.

Comment: I don't know if you have resources available to create something like this, even big companies like Google has to spend several years on Angular and its still not perfect...

Comment: It is not matter of resources what am asking here. So please be relevant in your comments.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are already frameworks out there to help one build web app UIs, [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) and [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) to name a few

Comment: You know there was unix and other systems when Linus reinvent most of the part of the wheel. I mean Linux. So I am asking here other part of wheel which should remain same.

Comment: Please leave comment if you down vote

Comment: I was edit my question. If it still not specific let me know.

Comment: Rewriting all, even DOM manipulation and data-binding your self worth every penny when it comes to speed, flexibility but also easy to maintain over long with relative small efforts. I stopped using frameworks because they always die or get incompatible or its just annoying..I would recommend looking at open-source projects doing what you want(cloud9, maqetta, Intel-XDK are such  projects), and then decide which fits best to you, it can take 2 - 3 years alone and you will constantly rewriting the same thing! Right now 'web-components' are hot and the way to go when doing a custom ux-framework.

Answer (score 24):

> I apologize that this answer is extremely long and at times may seem somewhat off-topic, but please keep in mind that the question was not very specific. If it is improved, or made less general, then I will gladly remove the superfluous parts, but until then, just bear with me. This is somewhat of a compilation of the other answers here, in addition to my own thoughts and research. Hopefully my ramblings will be at least somewhat helpful for answering this question.

### General Tips for Frameworks

Frameworks are a ton of work, so don't spend all of that time for nothing. *Work Smarter, Not Harder.* In general, you should remember these things when creating a framework:

1. **Don't Reinvent the wheel**: There are tons of great frameworks out there, and if you create a framework that does the exact same thing as another framework, you've wasted a ton of your time. Of course, understanding what goes on inside another library is a great way to make your own library better. Quoting @ShadowScripter, "knowledge -> innovation." However, don't try to rewrite jQuery by yourself. :)
2. **Solve a Problem**: All good frameworks (and programs) start with a problem they are trying to solve, then design an elegant solution to solve this problem. So don't just start writing code to "create a custom UI framework," but rather come up with a specific problem you want to solve, or something you want to make easier. jQuery makes selecting and manipulating the DOM easier. Modernizr helps developers identify the features supported by a browser. Knowing the purpose of your framework will make it more worthwhile, and may even give it a chance of becoming popular.
3. **Fork, don't rewrite**: If the problem you aim to solve is already partially solved by another framework, then fork that framework and modify it to fully fit your needs. There's no shame in building of the work of others.
4. **Optimize and Test**: This is kind of a no-brainer, but before publishing version 1.0 on your website, test every single part of the function, under every single possible scenario, to make sure it won't crash and burn in production. Also, another no-brainer, minify your code (after testing) for performance benefits.
5. **[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple_Stupid)**: Don't repeat yourself, and keep it simple, stupid. Pretty self-explanatory.
6. **Stick to Stable**: (This is mostly my personal opinion) Unless you're trying to create a framework specifically targetted to HTML5 in Chrome 31, using experimental features and unstable code will make your framework slower, uncompatible with older browsers, and harder to develop with.
7. **Open Source**: (Another of my opinions) It takes years for huge companies like Google with thousands of dollars invested to create frameworks (e.g. AngularJS) so it is an excellent idea to make your source openly available. Having a community of developers contributing to your project will make development faster, and will make the end product faster, bug-free, and better all around. Of course, if you're going to sell it, that's another story...

For more information about best practices when making libraries, take a look at these links:

- [Javascript Library Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850022/javascript-library-design)
- [Javascript Module Pattern: In Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)
- [Best Practices in Javascript Library Design](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/YTVideo/best-practices-javascript-library-281.aspx)
- [Building a Javascript Library](http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/)

---

### Types of Frameworks

The first thing you need to think about, as mentioned above, is what functionality you want your framework to provide. Here are is the [list of types of frameworks/libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) (thanks to @prong for the link). *For a much more comprehensive list, see [jster](http://jster.net/), which has 1478 libraries, put into 8 categories, each with several subcategories.*

- DOM (manipulation) related
- GUI-related (Widget libraries)
- Graphical/Visualization (Canvas or SVG related)
- Web-application related (MVC, MVVM, or otherwise)
- Pure Javascript/AJAX
- Template Systems
- Unit Testing
- Other

As you can see from the link, there are already dozens of libraries and frameworks in each of these categories, so there's not exactly much room for something new. That being said, I don't want to discourage you- who knows, you could create the next bootstrap or jQuery. So, here are some resources about each type of framework.

> Note: you can't say that any type is better than the others, they simply are designed for different goals. It's like comparing apples and oranges.

**[DOM (manipulation) related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#DOM_.28manipulation.29_related)**
These types of libraries are designed to interact with, modify, and control the DOM of a website. Here are just a few of the things they do:

- Select Elements in the DOM (`$("div#id .class")`)
- Add/Remove Elements in the DOM (`$("div#id .class").remove()`)
- Edit Attributes of Elements  in the DOM (`$(div#id .class).height("30px")`)
- Edit CSS of Elements in the DOM (`$(div#id .class).css("property","value")`)
- Add listeners for various events taking place in the DOM (`$(div#id .class).click(callback)`)

The most notable of these, of course, is jQuery, and it has one of the largest user bases of any Javascript library. However, [it is by no means perfect](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/09/jquery-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/), and if your library wants to compete, the best thing to do would be to make it excel in the areas that jQuery fails- speed, fragmentation, and "spaghetti" code. (The last two aren't completely in your control, but there are certainly things that you can do to make it easier for users to use the most update version, and keep their code maintainable)

**[GUI-related (Widget libraries)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#GUI-related_.28Widget_libraries.29)**
I think that this may be the type of framework you're looking to create. These types of libraries provide widgets (datepickers, accordians, sliders, tabs, etc.), interactions (drag, drop, sort, etc.) and effects (show, hide, animations, etc.). For these, people are looking for quantity- the best frameworks out there have several useful widgets/effects that work well. This is one case where it's "the more, the merrier," of course, if it works properly.

**[Graphical/Visualization (Canvas or SVG related)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Graphical.2FVisualization_.28Canvas_or_SVG_related.29)**
The purpose of these libraries is to control animations on the page, specifically on an HTML5 Canvas. These feature animations and sprites for games, interactive charts, and other animations. Again, successful graphical libraries have many, many sprites/animations. For example kineticjs has over 20 different sprites available. However, make sure that quantity does not compromise performance and overall quality.

**[Web-application related (MVC, MVVM, or otherwise)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Web-application_related_.28MVC.2C_MVVM.2C_or_otherwise.29)**
Basically, the idea is to provide a layout for the users to put their code in, typically separating the model (data) from the view(what the user sees), with a small controller to provide an interface between these two. This is known as [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). While it is by no means the only software pattern to base a framework off of, it has become quite popular recently, as it makes development much easier (that's why [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is so popular).

**[Pure Javascript- AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Pure_Javascript.2FAJAX)**
This should really be two categories. The first, AJAX libraries, are often paired with a server side library and/or database (though not always) and are designed to make connections with a server and get data asynchronously. The second, "Pure Javascript" are designed to make Javascript easier to program in, as a language, provide helpful functions and programming constructs.

**[Template Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Template_Systems)**
This might also be the type of framework you're looking to create. The idea is to provide components that developers can use. There's a thin line between Template Frameworks and Widget Frameworks (which [twitter bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com), one of the most popular template frameworks, crosses a lot). While widget frameworks just give a bunch of little elements that can be put in a site, template frameworks give structure to a website (e.g. responsive columns), in addition to making it look good.

**[Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Unit_Testing)**
This type of framework is designed to let developers test, or systematically ensure the correctness, of their code. Pretty boring, but also really useful.

**[Other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#Other)**
This type of framework is for really specific purposes that don't really fit into any of these other categories. For example, [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/) is designed for rendering math interactively in web pages. It doesn't really fit into any other category. However, these types of frameworks aren't bad or useless, they're just unique. A perfect example is [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), a library for detecting a browser's support for features. While it doesn't really have any direct competitors, can't be put into any of the other categories, and does a very small task, it works very well, and is very popular as a result.

**[More Types](http://jster.net/)**
There are a bunch of other types of libraries. Below are the categories (I'm not listing subcategories because that would take half an hour to copy down) that JSter puts their 1478 libraries into:

- Essentials
- UI
- Multimedia
- Graphics
- Data
- Development
- Utilities
- Applications

Comment: +1 For good answer. If there will not be any other answer I will award bounty to your answer.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the "reinventing the wheel" argument. I mean, there is some benefit to gain from it. If anything you'll learn the ins and outs on how to make a wheel... and then maybe go on to make a tire for the wheel. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @ShadowScripter If the library to be redone is only 5 lines of code, then yes, it's fine to reinvent the wheel, so "you'll learn the ins and outs on how to make a wheel." However, this is impractical for huge programs like jQuery.

Comment: @ShadowScripter Also, continuing with your metaphor, is it really necessary to understand how to make a wheel in order to make a tire? I agree that you should know how the wheel works, but I don't think you need to know how to make it. Anyway, this is getting too abstract for me :). My point is, it's unnecessary to rewrite a whole library just to improve it slightly. Building on top of, instead of redesigning completely is a better use of your time.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 And it's a good point. The point *I* was trying to get across was: knowledge -> innovation

Comment: @ShadowScripter Okay, that makes sense now. Please see my edits.

Comment: @Phoenix please also accept this answer.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you really want. The first distinction that needs to be made is between a  Javascript UI framework (which provides structure to the app), an HTML UI Framework (Presentation) and Widget Libs.

Javascript Frameworks such as [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [angular](http://angularjs.org/), [ember](http://emberjs.com/), and [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) provide MVC-like structure to the app.

UI frameworks such as YUI, bootstrap, and Foundation provide a consistent HTML and CSS base.

Widget Libraries such as jQuery UI, Fuel UX, and Kendo UI provide ready made widgets.

There are also fully-fledged frameworks which provide things across the board, such as Google Closure tools, Dojo with Dijit.

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) list pretty much sums it up, and here is the [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

In order to find the best way to create a framework, first ask this question: Can any of the above frameworks/libraries solve all or some of the problems/requirements I have?

If something solves all the problems, you can use it right away.

**If something solves your problem partially, you can start by extending/forking that project/framework.**

Follow DRY and KISS rules. Only solve a problem which nobody has solved as of now.

Comment: +1 for your answer. However I ask here what is best approach to create one of this kind of library? I mean which way is better comparatively to other in terms of design(i does not mean web design approach) approach of library?

Comment: actually that would harm your framework, except you can afford it of course.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, there is already a good solution: [Google Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/). This is what Google uses. It shows the approach of mixing HTML, CSS and JS. I wouldn't say it's perfect, but I believe it's one of the best ones at this moment. Its architectural principles rely on proven component based and OOP concepts, and it's accompanied with a static compiler for Javascript. It's definitely worth of studying before baking your own solution.

Answer (score 3):

*I'd like to say that cloudcoder2000's answer sums it up nicely. I'm just writing this answer because it didn't seem right in the comment section :P*

---

If you are thinking of making another framework, my suggesting is to stop thinking.

First find the thing in current implementations which troubles you the **most**, and try to find how you can improve it. Contribute to existing projects, nearly all of them are open source anyways. Also, you don't really need to be a JS-ninja to get into their midst. Take a fork, and get started. Once you're done, and feel that you're code is good enough, make it known to the original repo's maintainers that you have done improvements, and are looking for it to be merged into the project.

*Keep in mind here that I'm not discouraging you from solving the problem at all.*

I'm just pointing out that there are so **MANY** frameworks out there, wouldn't it be better if you went ahead and contributed to one of them instead of going for complete glory and implementing a full framework yourself? Making a framework is hard, but getting people interested in your framework is **HARD. Really Really HARD**, even for Google! Only once Angular got a very good documentation (which itself took quite some time, and resources, of Angular evangelists), that it has gathered so much steam. So, I'm just saying that instead of creating your own monument, perhaps lending a hand to others would be a more worthwhile exercise.

Most importantly though, is the fact that since you are *just starting out*, I *presume* you wouldn't have much experience designing frameworks, or thinking in those design terms even. It would of **immense** value if you contribute to existing projects. Then you will be gathering **knowledge** and **experience** of how things are built. *Then*, you'll be more confident. *Then*, you can go ahead and make your own framework! *Then* you'll be more equipped to tackle mammoth projects such as designing a framework. *And Then*, my friend, will you make something which would be worth the time of countless developers.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Build a skinny DOM and only focus on JS code to make it more efficient.

---

**Long answer**

A good architect always replies with "it depends." You can't have one single framework that enjoys all others' benefits and suffers from no disadvantages, all at once. There's always a trade-off.

In order to create a framework that is really lightweight, you would probably want the lightest DOM (HTML) structure. However, having a skinny DOM might have the cost of more JS code. So you would probably try to write the most efficient code. You can start [here](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html).

Needless to say, you should be keeping the **open-close** principle, and have the stylesheets separated from HTML, using only classes and never inline styling. I would suggest using [less](http://lesscss.org/). It makes the implementation faster, and the result is pure css so you suffer from no performance issues around it.

Answer (score 1):

I must respectfully disagree with [cloudcoder2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827555/cloudcoder2000),

From a young age I have been being told don't re-invent the wheel, but why?

During the last 3.5 years, I have re-invented almost all of my web controls using javascript/html/css. From the extremely complex; for example a grid, rich text editor, tree view, dialog.  To the very simple, like a progress bar, dropdown. What I gained is a better understanding of html/js/css.

No pain, no gain. I'm so happy with what I was doing these years as I learned more than others.

Some of the controls I re-invented, I think, are much better than the popular ones, like telerik, jquery mobile, extJS. For example, my tree view is fully customizable, with it one can build very complex trees.

So, I encourage you re-invent the wheels, and you will definitely get more than you expected. But also, from the beginning, you need to learn the source code of the popular controls, and re-invent them. You will be very happy when you find yourself be able to make the controls better.

#### Then the tips on creating HTML controls:

**1.** use jquery;

**2.** write jquery plugins(jQuery.prototype...) for simple controls, while define classes for complex controls;

**3.** separate css from html and js files. Define the html template in js, don't use html files, which make using the controls hard.

Regards,

Leo

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Leo, I'm beginner to web development. I was doing windows form application for last 3 years. I would like to 're-invent the wheel' in js/html/css. Could you suggest where to start?

Comment: here is an example: http://jquerygrid.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

For best performance in your UI design, you need to use a lightweight JavaScript framework like angular or backbone, Twitter Bootstrap for the UI, AJAX for base script load and use gzip compression in your app to make it lightweight and help the UI render faster.

Comment: I do not want some ready made framework. I want to see best framework design(do not confuse with web design) approach. In order to create my one.